# How to execute a loop using avada fusion toggle shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I am using a custom post type to allow a client to add job listings to their site using the Avada Theme. The desired archive layout involves using pre-built fusion toggles to display each job post (individual job posts use Advanced Custom Fields). I have created a custom archive-employment.php to run my code for this page in and was successfully able to create toggles for each post, however, each toggle acts independently and does not close when another one opens. Here is what I have so far:

```
   <?php echo do_shortcode ('[fusion_accordion type="accordions" boxed_mode="" border_size="" border_color="" background_color="" hover_color="" divider_line="" title_font_size="" icon_size="" icon_color="" icon_boxed_mode="" icon_box_color="" icon_alignment="" toggle_hover_accent_color="" hide_on_mobile="" class="" id="hr-employment"]'); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : 
        while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php $title = get_the_title(); ?>
            <?php $dept = get_field("department"); ?>
            <?php $jobType = get_field("job_type"); ?>
            <?php $salary = get_field("salary"); ?>
            <?php $desc = get_field("job_description"); ?>
            <?php $addInfo = get_field("additional_info"); ?>
            <?php echo do_shortcode ('[fusion_toggle title="'.$title.'" open="" ]Department: '.$dept.' </br> Job Type: '.$jobType.' </br> Salary: $'.$salary.' </br> Description: <a href="'.$desc['url'].'">PDF</a>[/fusion_toggle]'); ?>
        </div>
     <?php endwhile;
            endif; ?>
    <!--<?php echo do_shortcode ('[/fusion_accordion]'); ?>   Plain Text Error; Not a Valid Shortcode Operator -->
```

How do I make it so that the [fusion_accordion] shortcode is executed only once and is wrapped around the [fusion_toggle] shortcodes that run in the while loop?

Comment: can you show us the output as well?